# Recorrer Array en php

Tags: php, javascript

**Resuelto**

Me estoy volviendo loco con un tema aparentemente sencillo pero no do con la tecla.

Tengo una funcion ajax que le pasa a un php un array,  una vez en php recorro el array y hago una serie de cosas.

```
function asigTareaUsr(id){
    tAsig = sessionStorage.getItem('tareasAsig');
**var Asig=[tAsig];** //Esto es lo que estaba mal 
    
    var parametros = {
        "idUsr": id,
        "tAsig": tAsig, //Array
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: "php/asigTar.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    
        }
    });
}
```

PHP

```
<?php   //Este archivo asigna una o varias tareas a un usuario
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();

$id=$_POST["idUsr"]; //Id del usuario 
$tAsig=$_POST["tAsig"]; //Id de Tareas Array
$data = array( "usr" => $id);  
$data_string = json_encode($data);


foreach ($tAsig as $dataAcc)  //Recorro el json y lo voy almacenando en la variable array creada
        {  
            
            file_get_contents('http://web/Aesdat/v1/acc_tar/'.$dataAcc.'?api_key=AO', null, stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => array('Content-Type: application/json'."\r\n"
            .'accept: application/json' . "\r\n"
            .'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string) . "\r\n"),
            'content' => $data_string)
            )
        ));
        
    }
    
?>
```

Decir que al hacer un echo desde el servidor con el contenido del array, cuando hago un alert desde ajax, veo el contenido del array, entiendo que el array  se pasa bien.

***Estaba mal la parte en la que asigno el array a la variable para pasarla a php.***

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema exactamente?

Comment: ¿Tu última edición significa que resolviste el problema? Si no lo has resuelto, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: EL problema es que los resultados obtenidos no eran los esperados. Como es normal el resultado obtenido es lo que yo le he dicho que haga en código fuente pero en agún sitio estaba equivocándome, Al parecer el problema estaba en la declaración del array..